# Unable to create j2me webservice client for a class with cyclic reference

Tags: java, web-services, java-me

**Server**

```
import javax.jws.WebService;
@WebService(endpointInterface = "SomeService")
public class SomeServiceImpl implements SomeService{
        @Override
        public Parent getParent() {
            return new Parent();
        }
}

public class Parent {   
     private Child child;
        //Getter,Setter
}

public class Child {    
    private Parent parent;
        //Getter,Setter
}
```

**J2ME client**

```
C:\WTK2.5.2_01\bin>wscompile.exe -gen -cldc1.1 -verbose config.xml
[RemoteInterfaceGenerator: Generating Java class for: SomeService.java]
[CustomClassGenerator: generating JavaClass for: getParent]
[CutomClassGenerator: generating JavaClass for: getParentResponse]
[CustomClassGenerator: generating JavaClass for: parent]
[CustomClassGenerator: generating JavaClass for: child]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at com.sun.j2mews.sg.StubGenerator.isValid(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.j2mews.sg.StubGenerator.isValid(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.j2mews.sg.StubGenerator.isValid(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.j2mews.sg.StubGenerator.isValid(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.j2mews.sg.StubGenerator.isValid(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.j2mews.sg.StubGenerator.isValid(Unknown Source)
```